# How can I change the placeholder/label color inside a v-text-field?

Tags: css, vuetify.js

I'm trying to change the color of both the label and the text being inputted by the user on a `v-text-field`. I've tried applying the `color` prop to it, but it only changes de bottom divider's color. What should I do to get it as I want?

This is my actual code:

```
<v-text-field label="Search here!" color="blue lighten-1">
    <template slot="append">
        <v-btn class="blue--text text--lighten-1" flat>
            <v-icon>search</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
    </template>
</v-text-field>
```

NOTE: I've removed some props as the `v-model` one, just to increase readability

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQ8AX.png) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWshA.png) are the actual results i'm getting. But what i would like is to get the 'Find a user' text on the same `blue lighten-1` Material Design color always (not only when there has been no text inputted), as well as such inputted text in the same color (not in black).

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it by overwriting the CSS default classes:

```
.custom-placeholder-color input::placeholder {
  color: red !important;
  opacity: 1;
}

.custom-label-color .v-label {
  color: red;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

[EDIT]

You can change the input color to have the text red/any other color:

```
.custom-placeholder-color input,
.custom-label-color input{
  color: red !important;
}
```

Codepen updated here:

https://codepen.io/fabiozanchi/pen/RmQbBd

Comment: Thank you very much! I could change the placeholder and label color with the codepen you provided :) But still, I couldn't manage to change the color of the text that is written inside the text field; it keeps being black. Any idea on how to change it?

Comment: Sure, you can use the custom classes and the input to change the colors. I have updated the Codepen.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This did the magic. As well, I couldn't get it to work because I was putting the CSS inside a `<style scoped>` tag, not a common `<style>` one. I don't exactly know why does that happen, but I guess using the class name only for that template should do the trick. Thanks :)