# How to change the font color of placeholder of v-text-filed in Vue?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have

```
<v-text-field hide-details class="search-field" id="name-input" placeholder="Search by name" v-model="search"></v-text-field>
```

in my code, and I want to change the font color of the placeholder.
In my css:

```
  .search-field input::placeholder{
    color: red!important;
  }
```

But it doesn't work.

[image]

Inside the `v-text-field` it is an `input` as shown below:

[image]

Could anyone point out where I did wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Font _size_ or _colour_? Try putting a space between `red` and `!important`. _Ed: ok, I just checked about the space and it doesn't matter. Still looks nicer though_

Comment: Use your browser's dev-tools to inspect the styles on the element. Chances are, Vuetify is providing a more specific selector for the placeholder styling

Comment: Color. I tried but it doesn't work. It is werid, I tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56262429/how-can-i-change-the-placeholder-label-color-inside-a-v-text-field, it works in Codepen, but doesn't work in my code.

Answer (score 2):

You can change placeholder color like this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    search: ''
  }
})
```

```css
.theme--light.v-input.search-field input::placeholder {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
        <v-text-field hide-details class="search-field" id="name-input" placeholder="Search by name" v-model="search"></v-text-field>
        <v-text-field hide-details class="search-field-2" id="name-input" placeholder="Search by name" v-model="search"></v-text-field>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Just follow the selectors you find in the dev console. To overwrite the values you need to be more "specific" than those created by **Vuetify**.